# Robotic arm chassis

Tags: robotic-arm, manufacturing, chassis

I've been curious about how the plastic chassises of the robotic arms in robotic competitions are manufactured. For instance, the following arms clearly have 10-20 plastic parts each, if not more:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Injection moulding such large parts can easily cost \$5k per mould, so it wouldn't quite make sense to me that university projects would spend \$100k into the chassis production alone when only merely several units are needed. By looking at the finishing, they don't seem to be 3D printed. How are the chassises actually made though?

Comment: All of the robot examples you showed are purchased machines.

Comment: @morbo In that case, does that mean the challenge is mostly a software challenge then? Is it fair to say that the teams involved didn't make hardware innovations?

Comment: At most new tooling. Generally those comps would be for planning innovations, or the like, as you said yes

Comment: @morbo What do you mean by tooling?

Comment: End effector i suppose would be more common to say

Comment: 100k on molds is **nothing** in the collaborative industry, considering that most of the top sellers are netting [over 5 billion USD a year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FANUC), and many are very close to that figure, It's literally a drop in the bucket. The first image I'm almost certain is a KUKA, which are the runner up for biggest robot sellers'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The robot manufacturers or the industries that use them will sponsor these competitions; these sponsorships generally take the form of donated equipment.

Beyond the tax writeoff of donating the equipment, a robot arm manufacturer gets the university to turn out students that have experience with their particular arm. Similar benefit for industries.

If you are, say, an automotive company, then maybe you'll donate the same kind of robot arms and PLCs that you use to a university. Everyone in the engineering department at that university will then train up on *your company's* preferred robot arms, using *your company's* preferred PLCs, and then you can come hire up the best-performing students from the graduating classes.

The company gets good PR for sponsoring the competition, a tax writeoff for donating the equipment, and gets a steady stream of people that already have a working knowledge of interfacing to the equipment they'll use in their professional career.

A lot of companies will do this, to get people used to using *their* software, etc. My university had everyone using Microsoft Office (Word vs. LaTeX),  Matlab (vs. Mathematica), Autodesk Inventor (vs. Solidworks) and so on. Those were all provided free to me while I was a student.